# html and css classes not showing in html template mail

Tags: html, asp.net

I send mail using a html template in the system I prepared. The mail content that I prepared with the mail.html file does not come completely. I have added both the mail.html content below and the asp.net code snippet showing how I sent it. When you look at the photos, you will see the differences. Thank you in advance for your help

**mail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Tikom - Crm</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-8 my-3 px-0 shadow-lg">
        <div class="jumbotron bg-light m-0 px-3 pb-1">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div style="
                        width: 100%;
                        position: absolute;
                        height: 80px;
                        background-image: url(https://www.trabzon.bel.tr/images/logo_ust.svg);
                        background-position: left bottom;
                        left: 3%;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                </div>
                <div style="
                        width: 100%;
                        position: absolute;
                        height: 80px;
                        background-image: url(https://crm.trabzon.bel.tr/assets/images/tikom.png);
                        background-position: right bottom;
                        right: 5%;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                </div>
                <div class="col p-0"
                     style="height: 80px;
                            background-image: url(https://www.trabzon.bel.tr/images/suliet_cizim.png);
                            opacity: .5;
                            background-position: center bottom;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col px-5 text-right">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Trabzon-B%C3%BCy%C3%BCk%C5%9Fehir-Belediyesi-530262227138695/?ti=as"
                       class="text-dark">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" style="font-size:28px"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/TrabzonBelTr" class="mx-1 text-dark">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:28px"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/trabzonbeltr/?igshid=qxtt010x7v52" class="text-dark">
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:28px"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>                
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col px-5">
                    ${message}
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="my-4">
            <address class="font-weight-light text-center">
                <a class="px-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Gülbaharhatun Mah. Kahramanmaraş Cad. No:201 Ortahisar/TRABZON</span>
                </a>
            </address>
            <address class="font-weight-light">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <a href="mailto:info@trabzon.bel.tr" style="color: black;" class="px-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><span style="cursor: pointer;"> info@trabzon.bel.tr</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <a href="tel:+90 462 224 61 61" style="color: black;" class="px-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><span style="cursor: pointer;"> +90 462 224 61 61</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <a href="tel:+90 462 224 61 67" style="color: black;" class="px-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-fax" aria-hidden="true"></i><span style="cursor: pointer;"> +90 462 224 61 67</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </address>
            <address class="font-weight-light text-center">
                <a href="www.trabzon.bel.tr" style="color: black;">
                    <i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i><span style="cursor: pointer;"> www.trabzon.bel.tr</span>
                </a>
            </address>
            <address class="text-center mt-5 mb-0">
                <small class="font-weight-light">
                    Bu e-posta Trabzon Büyükşehir Belediyesi tarafından gönderilmiştir.
                </small>
            </address>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p style="margin-bottom: 100px"></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**must be seen in the mail** [mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyfyK.png)

**asp.net code**

```
public async Task sendEmail(string emailAddress, string title, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                var mailHtml = File.ReadAllText("HtmlTemplates/mail.html").Replace("${message}", message);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mailHtml)))
                {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("***", "Trabzon İletişim ve Koordinasyon Merkezi", Encoding.UTF8), new MailAddress(emailAddress));
                    mail.Subject = title;
                    mail.Body = message;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Body = mailHtml;

                    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("****");
                    mailClient.Port = 587;
                    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");
                    mailClient.EnableSsl = false;

                    var transportProp = mailClient.GetType().GetField("_transport", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var transport = transportProp.GetValue(mailClient);
                    var authModulesProp = transport.GetType()
                        .GetField("_authenticationModules", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var authModules = authModulesProp.GetValue(transport) as Array;
                    var activemodule = authModules.GetValue(authModules.Length - 1);
                    var newModules = Array.CreateInstance(activemodule.GetType(), 1);
                    newModules.SetValue(activemodule, 0);

                    authModulesProp.SetValue(transport, newModules);

                    mailClient.Send(mail);

                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

content that appears in mail as below:
[image]

Comment: check bootstrap cdn is downloadable on that system..Moreover include classes as inline style

Comment: Many mail clients will not allow downloading of external files into the email (e.g. CSS files), so you might have to add the relevant CSS inline in a style tag. Also, HTML mail is a historical mess with much poorer standards compliance and implementation than standard browser rendering - so even then you may find the mail doesn't display quite how you expected (and this can vary from mail client to mail client too).